# Создать проект на Spring Boot в Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, spring-boot

Изучаю Spring не первый месяц. Пытаюсь создать проект в среде Intellij IDEA как обычно:

1. Выбираю New project -> Spring Initializer
2. Далее выбираю Мавен и версию Java, остальное по умолчанию:
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. Затем выбираю стандартные депенденси, я их неоднократно использовал. Версию Spring Boot не меняю, оставляю ту что предлагают:
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В итоге создался проект. В нём несколько косяков:

1. В pom файле всё красное:
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. Если развернуть дерево папок, то они не выделены цветом. Хотя java source должна быть синей, java test зелёной, а resources иметь оранжевый ярлычок. Также java классы должны быть с синим значком:
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. На вкладке Maven справа помимо Lifecycle должен быть раздел dependencies и там все мои спринговые зависимости, которые я ранее заказывал, но раздела dependencies нет:
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попытался исправить всё так:

1. Сначала директории main->java, main->resources, test->java помечаю с помощью пункта меню "Mark Directory as":
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. Но после этого в самом SpringBootApplication-классе всё становится красным:
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. Но при этом в классе появляютя зелёные галочки (строка 7 и 9) для запуска. Пытаюсь запустить. Получаю такие ошибки:
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Где-то увидел видос с точно такой же проблемой. Там сказано что типа нестабильное интернет-соединение и поэтому зависимости могут не скачиваться. Надо попробовать более старые версии, которые уже скачаны. В pom-файле в разделе parent пытаюсь выбрать более старую версию. Когда печататю 2.5 то среда сама мне предлагает версию 2.5.5 Хорошо, выбрал то что предлагает среда:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В итоге это вообще никак не помогло. Да и с интернетом у меня вроде всё нормально.

В другой статье предлагают выбрать в меню File -> Invalidate Caches...  А затем Maven -> Reload all maven projects. Это тоже не помогло.

Версия студии Intellij IDEA 2020.2.1 Ultimate Edition. Я ей давно пользуюсь, раньше всё норм было.

В общем, подскажите, плиз, почему у меня вдруг всё перестало работать?

Comment: В общем, в итоге скачал и установил более новую версию Intellij IDEA, а именно: 2021.1.3   Только это мне и помогло.